# How do you write a simple and proper input pipe in C++

Tags: c++

I have been searching all over for a simple input Pipe example in C++.
Most of the pipes found is old unix style pipes.

Admitting that I am quite unfamiliar with piping, and my purpose is to create a c++ Apache Log pipe, so that all logs can be piped through my program. I assume that the minimum requirement is an input-pipe.

Currently my pipe is listed below.

I have established that when running the command : cat /pathto/access_log | ./myfunction , the output will produce an output like : 0 : 1: 14 HTTP GET found.
And I have established that the pipe gets its input from cin, and not from argv, something that might be stupefying and trivial for the professional programmer.

My current problem now, is that the prgrogram stop when all inputs have been piped in. Trying to type something in the terminal, seem to work, but the input seem to be disregarded and not handled.

But my question is : Is this a properly written input pipe. And if not. What is missing?

```
void pipecommand(string strcommand, int &cnt1, int &cnt2, bool flag){

    //Extra code inserted here to handle http log entries
    //-------------

    int loc = strcommand.find("GET");
    if(loc != string::npos)
    {
        if(flag){cnt1++;}
        else{cnt2++;}
        cout << cnt1 << " : " << cnt2 << ": " << loc << " HTTP GET found" << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])                
{                                               
    string str_command = "";
    string argument = "";
    bool argument_f = false;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    bool isArg = false;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        argument = argv[1];
        argument_f = true;
    }
    while(getline(cin, str_command))  //getline inserted here
    {
        if(argument_f){
            isArg = true;
            pipecommand(argument, counter1, counter2, isArg);
            argument_f = false;
        }
        else{
            //getline(cin, str_command); 
            //Removed and inserted in while

            isArg = false;
            pipecommand(str_command, counter1, counter2, isArg);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To make the program exit when the pipe is closed, use the return value of `std::getline`.

Comment: i believe what you want doesn't really have to do with pipes but with input steams. Whether or not something is piped into your program or entered directly doesn't really change that you wan to exit once the stream is closed. Try running your program without piping the output of `ls` into it. If your program is waiting for input, you will be presented with a prompt. Once you close that (Control-D on most terminals) that's when you want your program to terminate.

Comment: Have a look at the [`std::istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I assume that if the intended usage is CustomLog " | myfunction ", the pipe needs to stay open and will wait for more input. To exit is not the issue, but why this function does not respond to terminal input after the ls -l command. Anything I write ... containing root, does not seem to compile.

Comment: A [**demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2686a92a88f8ab91) using `std::cin` (like suggested by @Thomas). All I needed to do was `for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) { /* ... */ }`. (The rest is provided by the OS / shell.)

Comment: I tested the demo code, and could not see any improvements I was looking for.

Comment: Based on the first comment (suggested by Thomas), i have reviewed and changed the code. By inserting the getline into the while statement, It works succsessfully as I was hoping for. The correct code is now provided above.